# Display data even for null values stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I made this query to show some aggregate data.
I am also interested in showing elements of a table that are not affected. After several useless tests I try to ask you for help.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROVA 
(
    NOME            IN VARCHAR2,
    COGNOME          IN VARCHAR2,
    CARTA            IN VARCHAR2,
    output OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS 
BEGIN
OPEN output FOR

SELECT
    dati.nome "NOME",
    dati.cognome "COGNOME",
    dati.carta "CARTA",
    dati.profilo "PROFILO",
    dati.s_denominazione "DENOMINAZIONE",    
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(numacc) > 0 THEN
            'TRUE'
        ELSE
            'FALSE'
    END     "ABILITATO",
    SUM(numacc) "NUMERO ACCESSI"  
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            d.codicepunto,
            d.s_denominazione,
            a.carta carta,
            c.nome nome,
            c.cog cognome,
            c.profilo profilo,
            coalesce(a.numacc, 0) numacc
        FROM
            tabellaA a
            JOIN tabellaB b
                ON a.id = b.id
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABELLAC c
                ON a.carta = c.carta
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABELLAD d
                ON b.punto = d.punto            
        WHERE
        (NOME IS NULL or c.nome = NOME)
        AND
        (COGNOME IS NULL or c.cog = COGNOME)
        AND
        (CARTA IS NULL or a.carta = CARTA)
        AND 
        sysdate BETWEEN a.datinivalacc AND a.datfinvalacc
    ) dati
GROUP BY
    
    dati.s_denominazione,
    dati.carta,
    dati.nome,
    dati.cognome,
    dati.profilo
ORDER BY
    dati.s_denominazione;

    
END ;
```

This is the result:

| NOME | COGNOME | CARTA | PROFILO | DENOMINAZIONE | ABILITATO | NUMERO ACCESSI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | Weah | 010101 | 1 | Torino | TRUE | 10 |
| Albert | Weah | 010101 | 1 | Milano | TRUE | 20 |
| (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | Napoli | FALSE | 0 |
| (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | Roma | FALSE | 0 |

This is what I would like to achieve:

| NOME | COGNOME | CARTA | PROFILO | DENOMINAZIONE | ABILITATO | NUMERO ACCESSI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | Weah | 010101 | 1 | Torino | TRUE | 10 |
| Albert | Weah | 010101 | 1 | Milano | TRUE | 20 |
| Albert | Weah | 010101 | 1 | Napoli | FALSE | 0 |
| Albert | Weah | 010101 | 1 | Roma | FALSE | 0 |

What am I missing?
The input parameters are all optional.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you had a 2nd NOME, would you have 8 rows? Do you want 1 row for each NOME and DENOMINAZIONE combination? You might want a **partition outer join**

Comment: `numacc` column have to be within *GROUP BY* list unless *CASE..WHEN* expression is aggregated. Btw, `dati.codicepunto` does not exists within the *SELECT* list, while it stays within *GROUP BY* list.

Comment: Yes @Kfinity. I look for a line for combination NOME and DENOMINAZIONE